# In which step in the checkout process is an user account is created?

Tags: rules, commerce

I'm using Commerce Kickstart (Drupal 7.23, Kickstart 7.x-2.9). New commerce orders are linked to user accounts. If an account with the same email address does not exist yet, a new account is created. This is the normal flow.

I would like to know in which part of the checkout process, that account is created or linked to, because I've found some cases where the commerce order is linked to anonymous user with no reason.

Comment: If you're really using Drupal 7.23, then forget whatever you're doing ... Hurry to get your Drupal core version updated. Even if it was only because of the security issue in 7.32 ... Actually upgrading may not be sufficient ... Hopefully you still have an "ap^propriate" backup to restore ... PS: I realize this is NOT a real answer to the question, but hopefully this comment doesn't get flagged for deletion.(until the OPer has indicated the 7.23 'issue' is resolved).

Answer (score 0):

This happens in Commerce Checkout through Rules.

1. Rule *commerce_checkout_order_convert* will check the order's given mail against existing users and automatically assign it.
2. Rule *commerce_checkout_new_account* creates a new account if the mail given doesn't match a user.

See the rule "Create a new account for an anonymous order". It creates a new user based off of the mail provided by the anonymous user during checkout.